# Android Sqlite watch table for data updates

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Say my application has a `ListView` that displays information from a Sqlite database, using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Other threads will be updating the relevant tables in the database, and the `ListView` should update automatically.

The `SimpleCursorAdapter` I create doesn't seem to be watching the database for updates. I call the following function after updating the table.

```
((CursorAdapter) this.getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just a SimpleCursorAdapter you will need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the ListView to force it to refresh.